# Way of streaming data from a NodeJS server to .NET CORE?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, .net

Excuse me, for I am new to .NET and Visual studio:

I want to stream data from my NodeJS server (Visual Studio Code), to my .NET Core app (Visual Studio).

I have posted on here before and have gotten it taken down due to there being answers already posted, but I was researching around a lot, and couldn't find any.

So the way I currently have it working is setting my NodeJS to write to a file, and then my .NET reads from the file at the same time. As you might be able to tell, this is far from ideal, as they conflict with each other and give errors a lot of the time, meaning the stream is nowhere close to perfect.

Then I found these things called [pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream?view=netframework-4.8), is there a way to create a "pipe" server on .NET or NodeJS and connect to it in the other framework to allow data to be easily passed between the two?

If you need any more clarification just let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create localhost RestAPI

```js
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('Received a POST HTTP method');
});
app.listen(8080) //port
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;

namespace RestAPI
{
    public class WebServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

        public WebServer(IReadOnlyCollection<string> prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");
            }

            // URI prefixes are required eg: "http://localhost:8080/test/"
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("URI prefixes are required");
            }

            if (method == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("responder method required");
            }

            foreach (var s in prefixes)
            {
                _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
            }

            _responderMethod = method;


            _listener.Start();


        }

        public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
           : this(prefixes, method)
        {
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
            {
                try
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(c =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                            try
                            {
                                if (ctx == null)
                                {
                                    return;
                                }

                                var rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                                var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                                string cmd = ctx.Request.RawUrl;
                                if (cmd.Contains("cmd="))
                                {
                                    cmd = cmd.Split('=')[1];
                                    cmd = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(cmd);
                                    Debug.WriteLine($"Request : {cmd}");
                                    Program.MakeCMD(cmd);
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                // ignored
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                // always close the stream
                                if (ctx != null)
                                {
                                    ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // ignored
                }
            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener.Close();
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static string prefix = "http://localhost:8081";
        public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            string txt = ""; //You can return some text/json
            return txt;
        }



        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, prefix);
                ws.Run();
            }
            catch
            {
                ConsoleLog.WriteLine("It looks like you are not running in administrator mode. Administrator Mode is required to start the web server!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I didn't found easier c# example :)

Then use XMLHttpRequest in node js and HttpClient in c#